# Azure pipeline - How to execute kubectl command

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, kubectl

I am trying to delete all namespaces prefixed with "dev-...". The command works fine on the commandline, but I'm not sure how to get this working in Azure Pipelines.

```
kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep dev- | xargs kubectl delete namespace
```

Answer (score 7):

Hi below pipeline should work with a defined service principal.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

# Delete All namespaces start with dev-
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_SP'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az aks get-credentials --resource-group $AKS_RG --name $AKS_NAME --admin
      kubectl get ns
      kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep dev- | xargs kubectl delete namespace
      kubectl get ns
  displayName: 'Delete All namespaces start with dev-'
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can mark it as an answer for the community ;)

Comment: This answer is a life saver ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found (at least for me) a much better way.

1. I'm adding my Cluster as Service Connection in Azure DevOps.
2. I use the `Kubernetes@1` to login and after that I just use a script block. This also works for `helm`.

```yaml
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'Kubernetes Login'
  # This is needed to run kubectl command from bash.
  inputs:
    connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: NAME OF YOUR SERVICE CONNECTION
    command: 'login'
- script: |
    kubectl get namespaces
  displayName: Execute kubectl
```

Comment: The other answer using `az aks get-credentials` didn't work for me because kubelogin is enabled on the cluster. This answer works even with kubelogin.